# Browser jumps to middle of page when loading HTML file

Tags: html

When I open an HTML file in Chrome, the page loads with some random h3 tag from the middle of the document (see last h3 tag in code below) at the top of the window, instead of the actual top of the page.  All of the content above that point is loads, but I have to scroll up to get to the top.

Same thing happens when I use Firefox, although it loads with the first h3 tag in my example at the top of the window.  Safari loads with the "Here is an example of bold text" paragraph at the top.  Any idea why this might be happening?

```
<h3>Audio</h3>
<audio src="07 Wake Up.mp3" controls>Here is some audio</audio>

<p>
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
</p>

<hr />

<h3 id="B">Bold text</h3>
<p>Here is an example of <b>bold text</b></p>

<h3>Bi-directional override</h3>

<p><bdo dir="rtl">This text will go from right to left.</bdo></p>
<p><bdo dir="rtl">.tfel ot thgir morf og lliw txet sihT</bdo></p>

<h3>Blockquotes</h3>

<p>Blockquotes specify a section that is quoted from another source, like in the passage below:</p>
<blockquote cite="http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/declaration_transcript.html">We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.</blockquote>

<h3 id="button">Buttons</h3>
```

Comment: Just added MCVE, and some clarifying details.  New to HTML and stackoverflow so let me know if anything is unclear.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

I think I know what's going on now.  The issue isn't with the tags that are loading at the top of the page, but with an autofocus button that appears a few lines down:

```
<h4>Autofocus button</h4>
<button type="button" autofocus>Autofocus button</button>
```

For anyone playing around with autofocus buttons, it seems like they cause the browser to "autofocus" (duh) on that point upon loading.  In my original case, my page loaded with the autofocus button on the bottom of the window, some headings from a few lines up at the top, and the actual top of the page nowhere in sight.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  Was definitely the autofocus that was causing problems.

Comment: Yes, it was the autofocus causing this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see you code, I would guess that you have an anchor tag somewhere that it is trying to navigate to. If you have a hash (#) in your URL, is in 99% likely. Otherwise, check your JS for a random scroll function that is attached to the wrong thing or perhaps running too early.

Without being able to see the code, this would be my best guess.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see a hash in the URL, but added the code to the original post to try and clarify.

Comment: Around where does it jump to? Do FF and Chrome always jump to the same place (even if not the same as each other)?

Comment: FF and Chrome always jump to the same place.  FF will jump slightly above the heading that says "Audio", and Chrome will jump directly to the heading that says "Buttons"