# Browser jumps to middle of page for a second before loading

Tags: html

My question is very similar to [Browser jumps to middle of page when loading HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471263/browser-jumps-to-middle-of-page-when-loading-html-file). Using Google Chrome, when I attempt to load up [joshnour.com](https://joshnour.com), the browser jumps to the middle of the screen for half a second, but I don't see any autofocus in my code nor am I loading from a # symbol (the 2 answers suggested in the linked question). This issue isn't present on Safari which is why I'm confused. The code is located on https://github.com/joshnour/joshnour.github.io.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a [Content Jumping](https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/) situation. Simple solution: use `min-height` instead of `height`. Some elements getting taller with `height` code, you can prevent getting taller by using `min-height`

Comment: Which elements should I be changing to use min-height?

Comment: Edit: I've figured out the issue and I was supposed to change the min-height in the CSS for the header class. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot the look your codebase sorry about that. That's good to hear, we solved your problem.